# Nusoap complexType parameters

Tags: php

When we want to define a `complexType` using nuSOAP, we use :

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType('Contact',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array( 'some' => array( 'name' => 'some', 'type' => 'xsd:string' ) )
```

And after that :

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType('AddressBook',
    'complexType',
    'array',
    '',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array',
    array(),
    array(
            array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'tns:Contact[]')
    ),
    'tns:Contact'
);
```

**Reference :** [above example reference](http://www.discorganized.com/php/a-complete-nusoap-and-flex-example-part-1-the-nusoap-server/)

Now I need to know what is the difference between above samples and what every parameter says:

```
'complexType',
'struct',
'all',
'',
```

And

```
'complexType',
'array',
'',
'SOAP-ENC:Array',
array(),
```

I researched for a while about this but still it's not clear for me.

It would be greate if you describe and mention some example about every sample.

***Thanks in advance***